# Laravel 5 and understanding MVC - How do I get the db data to my views?

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5

I’m new to Laravel 5 and the world of MVC.

I’ve installed Laravel 5 boilerplate project and everything works fine, out of the box. I can register and then login to the app.

I kind of understand the roles of Routes, Controllers, Models and Views, but I can’t figure out the syntax to simply retrieve data from my users database table, and display it in my home view (using HomeController).

I’m not sure which piece of code goes where, and how the syntax should be coded. In the code below, I'm logged in as a user, and I'm simply trying to display all the users from the user table.

Can you help? If I can understand how to the get the data from my database to my views, I’ll be good to go. I'm looking for simple examples. I've seen I lot of examples on the web, but for most, I don't even know where (controller, route, etc.) to copy the code provided.

I get the following error with the code below:

```
 FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 52: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found
```

routes.php

```
  Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return View::make('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

Home.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">List of users</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                <table>
                @foreach($users as $key => $value)
                 <tr>
                <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5 is namespaced and PSR-4 autoloaded, so in your controller `$users = User::all();` should be `App\User::all();` or `use App\User;` on the top of the file after the namespace declaration.

Your view is also incorrect. This `@foreach($users as $key => $value)` should be `@foreach($users as $user)` then you access the users attributes as normal fields: `$user->id`, `$user->name`, etc.

Another thing, the laravel 5 way to make a view is this (yours is not incorrect, it's just different syntax):

```
return view('user.index')->with(['users' => $users]);
```

or with some sorcery:

```
 return view('user.index')->withUsers($users);
```

Another tip that will really make you understand how stuff works: use tinker. Open up a console, go to the laravel folder and type `php artisan tinker`. There you can execute php code and check the output. Type `User::all()` and check the error. Then type `App\User::all()` and check the response.

Comment: Thanks @hfingler! I've added   use App\User;   at the top of my controller, then changed my public function index() to    $user = User::all(); return view('user.index')->with(['users' => $users]);     and finally I changed my view to replace   @foreach($users as $key => $value)  by  @foreach($users as $user)   but now I get the following error:  InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140: View [user.index] not found.

Comment: Do you have the file there? `resources/views/user/index.blade.php`?

Comment: No, the view i'm using is resources/views/home.blade.php

Comment: Then you must return the correct view, as in: `return view('home')->with ...`

Comment: Wow! My headache went away!! Thank you so much @hfingler